# Project tree in qt creator does not correspond to SOURCES variable in project file

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qmake

In the project file:

```
SOURCES = Test.cpp

warning("Sources before: " $$SOURCES)

qqqqqqqq = 12
isEmpty(qqqqqqqq) {
    SOURCES += options1.cpp
    warning("Var is empty !!!")
} else {
    SOURCES += options2.cpp
    warning("Var is NOT empty !!!")
}

warning("Sources after: " $$SOURCES)
```

Result output:

```
Project WARNING: Sources before:  Test.cpp
Project WARNING: Var is NOT empty !!!
Project WARNING: Sources after:  Test.cpp options2.cpp
```

All is ok. But in project tree I see 3 items instead 2:

```
Test.cpp
options1.cpp    <-- where does it come from?
options2.cpp
```

Somebody know where are from this options1.cpp (the "isEmpty(qqqqqqqq)" should not execute)?

---

P.S. Also I uses defineReplace for make user-function, makes some file manipulations (e.g. exctract some files by regex from list) and returns file list.

The result is same: returned file-list is ok in variable (I had check it using "warning()") but I have all files in project tree which has been used in my custom function like any if-statments ignored (but they does not ignored since I had check thi by "warning()"). I do not need this garbage (((

```
scl_root_dir = ./..
scl_dir_public_include = $$scl_root_dir/include
scl_dir_src =           $$scl_root_dir/src
scl_dir_core =          $$scl_root_dir/src/core
scl_dir_components =    $$scl_root_dir/src/components

scl_src_components = \
    \
    $$scl_dir_components/SclCore/SclCoreConv.cpp \
    $$scl_dir_components/SclCore/SclCoreExports.h \
    $$scl_dir_components/SclCore/SclCoreImpl.cpp \
    $$scl_dir_components/SclCore/SclCoreImpl.h \
    $$scl_dir_components/SclCore/SclCorePrint.cpp \
    $$scl_dir_components/SclCore/ProgBase.cl \
    $$scl_dir_components/SclCore/ProgCore.cl \
    \
    $$scl_dir_components/MathBase/MathBaseImpl.cpp \
    $$scl_dir_components/MathBase/MathBaseImpl.h \
    $$scl_dir_components/MathBase/ProgMathBase.cl \
    $$scl_dir_components/MathBase/ProgMathBaseEx.cl

# ##############################################################################

defineReplace(get_headers) {
    variable = $$1
    names = $$eval($$variable)
    files =

    for(name, names) {
        res = $$find(name, \.h$)
        count(res,1) {
            files += $$name
            message("FileH: " $$name)
        }
    }

    return($$files)
}

defineReplace(get_sources) {
    variable = $$1
    names = $$eval($$variable)
    files =

    for(name, names) {
        res = $$find(name, \.cpp$)
        count(res,1) {
            files += $$name
            message("FileCpp: " $$name)
        }
    }

    return($$files)
}

defineReplace(get_opencl) {
    variable = $$1
    names = $$eval($$variable)
    files =

    for(name, names) {
        res = $$find(name, \.cl$)
        count(res,1) {
            files += $$name
            message("FileCL: " $$name)
        }
    }

    return($$files)
}


#################################################################################################

warning("---------------------------------------------------------")

list_cpp = $$get_sources(scl_src_components)
list_hpp = $$get_headers(scl_src_components)
list_ocl = $$get_opencl(scl_src_components)

message("list_cpp: " $$list_cpp)
message("list_hpp: " $$list_hpp)
message("list_ocl: " $$list_ocl)

message("SOURCES before: " $$SOURCES)
message("HEADERS before: " $$HEADERS)

SOURCES = $$list_ocl

SOURCES = $$list_cpp $$list_ocl
HEADERS = $$list_hpp

message("SOURCES after: " $$SOURCES)
message("HEADERS after: " $$HEADERS)
```

Result in project tree (variables is OK):

```
Headers:
    components:
        MathBase:
            MathBaseImpl.cpp
            MathBaseImpl.h
            ProgMathBase.cl
            ProgMathBaseEx.cl
        SclCore
            ProgBase.cl
            ProgCore.cl
            SclCoreConv.cpp
            SclCoreExports.h
            SclCoreImpl.cpp
            SclCoreImpl.h
            SclCorePrint.cpp
Sources
    components:
        MathBase:
            MathBaseImpl.cpp
            MathBaseImpl.h
            ProgMathBase.cl
            ProgMathBaseEx.cl
        SclCore
            ProgBase.cl
            ProgCore.cl
            SclCoreConv.cpp
            SclCoreExports.h
            SclCoreImpl.cpp
            SclCoreImpl.h
            SclCorePrint.cpp
```

Comment: qmake file is a bullshit. Use [QBS](http://doc.qt.io/qbs/).

Comment: I do not argue )) But for project draft using qtcreator as IDE without making CMake-files - is very good for me.

Comment: Issue reported to QT group: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-15353